# How do I log visitors from my HTML-page via PHP, with code separation?

Tags: php, html, logging, visitor-pattern

I have a website where I want to log visitor's IP-address, browser and date/time to a txt-file, with help of a PHP-script. I have a PHP-script now that does what I want, it logs this information, but only if I visit the PHP-file. So when I visit my HTML, nothing adds to the txt-file.

I have tried both changing the HTML and the PHP, with for example require('home.html'); or $html = file_gets_contents("home.html"); in the PHP-file. But I'm very new to this language so I have no idea what I'm doing in this case.

And also, this is a school assignment, and **I can't use PHP-language in the HTML-file and vice versa**, so it needs to be separated. But it's ok to change the HTML-file as well, or both. Hope anyone can help me!

```
$handle = fopen('visitors.txt', 'a');
$data = "\nDate and time: " . date("Y.m.d, H:i:s") . "\nBrowser: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\nIP-address: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
echo file_get_contents('visitors.txt');
```

This is the code that works, but only for PHP visits, not visits for my website. (I know there is no code for that yet)

Comment: Whenever the visitor lands on your page, the PHP script will trigger (assuming it is hooked up correctly). If the file is called `index.php`, it will be loaded by default when the visitor goes to the site itself, assuming you have something like `yoursite.com/index.php`. From here you'll want to `include()` the HTML file for presentation. Remember, the visitors should be 'landing' on the PHP page, *not* the HTML page.

Comment: If you're using apache you could have access to a logfile on visitors with this information already. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great with @ObsidianAge solution. The assignment says I have to have index.html (not php), so I redirected to the php-script from index and in the php-script I used include(home.html)!